# Police puzzlement

Tags: lateral-thinking

At the crossroads, there was a traffic light.

A big truck, a horse-drawn wagon and a motorcycle rider are all standing and waiting for the green light.

As soon as the trucker saw that the light is about to turn green, he hit the gas. The horse was frightened by the sound and bit motorcycle rider's ear.

A policeman was called, and figured out that he ought to give **somebody** a ticket, since some rule was definitely broken to contribute to the resulting trauma.

The cop is honest, so won't lie on a ticket. Who got the blame and the ticket for breaking the rules?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ticket was given to

> the motorcyclist

for

> not wearing a helmet or head protection. If they had been, the horse could not have bitten their ear!

Then of course, the policeman might just ticket

> the wagon-driver

because

> it's against the law to drive a horse-drawn vehicle on that road!

Comment: Motorcyclists are not required to wear helmets in at least some areas.

Comment: @EngineerToast not required, or the requirement is not enforced? Bit of a difference between the two. If the cop is looking for reason to ticket, even a technicality offence will do.

Comment: (I don't know why @ isn't working, Nij, but it keeps getting removed.) I live in the U.S. [Here's a table](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/news/2011/06/state-by-state-guide-to-motorcycle-helmet-laws/index.htm) showing state-by-state laws. Only 20 of the 51 areas require helmets for all riders.

Comment: @EngineerToast - the puzzle originated in the state where it's required. That's the correct answer - the helmet was missing else there would be no ear bite.

Comment: Interesting. It's required in 100% of my country, and for good reason, so I wouldn't even conaider it being okay.

Comment: @user26771 That little tidbit is critical to the answer, then. I would suggest that, in a puzzle that requires us to pick out the one critical piece of information, you make it more of a story. That lets you slide in little details like that are critical to ensuring that only one, good answer is plausible instead of being too broad: `There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.`

Comment: @Nij I agree that they *should* be required but they still aren't everywhere. Motorcyclists without helmets are called "organ donors" by doctors around here.

Comment: @Nij Are half helmets legal elsewhere? [this girl](http://i.stack.imgur.com/miyKw.jpg) could still get her ear bitten.

Comment: @EngineerToast I'm not versed in the differentiation to that extent, so I don't know if it would be okay here, let alone elsewhere.

Comment: My recall is it is not in fact against the law to drive a horse-drawn vehicle on the road.

Comment: @Joshua generally, no. But there are huge numbers of roadways that restrict or outright ban the usage of certain vehicle types upon them. Motorways and bicycles, for example. Note also: "... on **that** road!"

Answer (score 4):

Here are two *more* plausible answers.

> The truck driver gets the ticket because his muffler was busted. Otherwise, the noise wouldn't have been loud enough to frighten the horse.

> The wagon driver gets the ticket because he was too close to the motorcyclist in front of him. Otherwise, the horse wouldn't have been close enough to bit his ear.

Comment: More plausible than what? An exhaust can be extremely loud, enough so to startle a person let alone a horse, and still be within regulatory limits. A horse can reach pretty far and still have been at sufficient distance to not be "too close" - the phrase *bumper-to-bumper* is barely not a literal description.

Comment: That's not to say those are bad answers to the puzzle, though, they're definitely creative. +1

Comment: @Nij Plausible answers, two more of them.

Comment: @f'' with the emphasis only on "more" it doesn't only read that way.

Comment: We don't know how many lanes there were.  The horse might have been beside the motorcyclist.

Comment: The truck was louder than the motorcycle?

Comment: @BobRodes a "big truck" could well be louder than a small motorbike. Even if its muffler was legal... ;)

Comment: @Nij Of course.  I didn't mean to suggest otherwise.  But a motorcycle could easily be louder than a "big truck" as well.  The point of my question is that since the puzzle statement doesn't specify the relative loudness of the two vehicles, and the poster's answer depends on the truck being louder than the motorcycle, perhaps the answer is not as plausible as he asserts.

Comment: @BobRodes it's possible to go either way, really, which is what makes it plausible.

Comment: @Well, to each his own, but that's what makes it for me less plausible than the others rather than more so.  Although I think it's more plausible than the truck driver jumping the light hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going with

> the truck driver

because

> he hit the gas when the light was only *about* to turn green, i.e., it wasn't green yet.

Comment: Vehicles are allowed to move forward even when the light remains red, so long as they do not enter the intersection. Truck (and bus) drivers here often leave a decent gap ahead of themselves, because of their lower acceleration from a dead stop, to help prevent a delay when the light does turn green. It's a good thought nonetheless :)